# Difference between: tableView.cellForRow and dataSource.cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

currently I am working on a project and the developers who started 
the project used to access the cells with

```
dataSource.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

but I am used to access cells with

```
cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Does anyone know the difference and which is better to use? The reason i ask is that `dataSource.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` caused us this crash.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempted to dequeue
>   multiple cells for the same index path, which is not allowed. If you
>   really need to dequeue more cells than the table view is requesting,
>   use the -dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: method (without an index
>   path). Cell identifier: CheckTableViewCell, index path:  {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}'

Comment: How and where you call those functions? For what purpose?

Comment: To access get cell(s) and to configure them. e. g. change the label of a cell

Comment: Please share some code where you calling cellForRow(at: indexPath) or dataSource.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is this:

```
dataSource.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is a method that your *dataSource* provides to the `UITableView`.  It is called by iOS to load a cell for a specific `indexPath`.  It works by dequeueing a reusable cell and filling in the information for that cell.

You typically do not call this.  iOS does.

```
cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

This method is provided by iOS to return the cell for a specific `indexPath` if that cell is currently on screen, or `nil` if the cell isn't on screen.

This method is for you to call if you have an `indexPath` and you need the associated cell.

---

Your error is happening because you are calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath` which dequeues a reusable cell to do its job.  The cell is already on screen and already has a cell associated with it, so now there are two, which makes no sense.

Comment: As an addition info regarding the error message, you dequeue cells in the first one (and only on this one).

Answer (score 1):

```
cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

At any point of time if you want to retrieve TableViewCell, You should use this.

```
dataSource.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

This is for loading cells in UITableview and is delegate method of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

To use a single for multiple times use below method.

```
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
            let cell =tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Your reuse Identifier", for: indexPath) as! YourCell
        return cell
    }
```